# Counterpart meaning of the word "Default" in NON IT World

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

What is the synonym/counterpart for the word "Default" in NON-IT WORLD? We use the word in computer programs/apps, meaning that there is a pre-specified/pre-defined setting or situation. The word has also different meanings in Law and Banking. But I want an alternative to use in our daily life: for instance, a physician may choose a "default" treatment for a common disease, or one can have a default position/view on a particular topic .... I want a counterpart meaning of the same word for everyday uses (non-IT world).

Comment: Pick one of the many synonyms of "usual" (e.g. classical, customary, traditional, conventional, ...) .

Comment: It would help to give a specific use case. The term in medicine is unlikely to be the same as in law or other fields with their own terminology. It's unreasonable to expect the same word to be used in every context, because English doesn't work like that even in general or colloquial speech. (There's also a difference between default by the book/statute/regulation and default by common sense or common wisdom.)

Comment: Note that "default" is also a verb.

Comment: The IT meaning of default settings is not unique.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably better classified as [informal] rather than [slang], **go-to** is often used for instruments, practices and even theories as well as indispensible people:

> *go-to* [1 of 3] [adjective]
>
> ...
>
> 2 [informal]: regularly or repeatedly chosen or employed for reliably
> good results
>
> - *O'Neal's go-to move has become a soft jump hook, which he can shoot with either hand.* —Chris Ballard
> - *While mozzarella may be the go-to cheese for pizza, … blue cheese … can also be great.* —Sam Gugino
> - *A waitress came by and Reacher ordered his go-to breakfast, which was coffee plus a short stack of pancakes with eggs, bacon, and maple
>   syrup.* —Lee Child

[[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/go-to)]

> - *Newton’s theory is used extensively in rocket science and ballistics.*
>   *For most purposes, it is the go-to theory for modeling the motion of*
>   *every day objects.*

[[Tim Anderson; Medium](https://medium.com/the-infinite-universe/science-may-not-be-true-dde5e437c303)]

Comment: I accpeted your answer, because I also heard this phrase a lot. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I suggest, for example

> The (physician's) **standard** treatment for ... is ...
> The (lawyer's) **standard** form of contract is ...
> The (physicist's) **standard** model of the ... is ...

[Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/standard) has

> **standard**
> a pattern or model that is generally accepted

Comment: thanks, "Standard" is good but I prefer "Go-To" as suggested here by @Edwin. Because if I say "Standard", there is a connotation/implication that an authority standardizes something, which may not be the case.

Answer (score 1):

**Fallback** (n.)

> Something on which one can fall back : RESERVE —often used
> attributively
>
> A *fallback* career
> A *fallback* position  [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fallback)

> Something upon which one may fall back, or to which one may resort; an
> **alternative plan or course of action** that may be used in an emergency
> or when other options have failed or become unavailable; **a reserve, a
> contingency**. [OED]

---

> When this is not possible, a reasonable ethical **fallback** is for
> the institution to guarantee timely referrals to ensure that patients
> receive continuity of care without facing an undue burden... [US
> Congress; *Do New Health Law Mandates Threaten Conscience
> Rights...*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Do_New_Health_Law_Mandates_Threaten_Cons/MU9KAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=medication%20no%20fallback&pg=PA155&printsec=frontcover)

> When mapping out a treatment approach, **fallback** plans are very
> important, as it may be necessary to attempt several interventions
> before a patient improves. [J. Gallo and W. Reichel; *Reiche's Care of
> the Elderly*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Reichel_s_Care_of_the_Elderly/8eqbZmQgUs4C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=medication%20as%20a%20fallback&pg=PA219&printsec=frontcover)

> Note also that lovastatin is dominated as a first-line medication in
> this segment of the population; it may, however, be cost-effective as
> a **fallback** medication for patients who cannot tolerate niacin, as
> indicated by the results for strategies using stepped. care. [M. Gold
> et al; *Cost-Effectiveness in Health and Medicine*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Cost_Effectiveness_in_Health_and_Medicin/V5mU2rBU-wwC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=medication%20no%20fallback&pg=PT443&printsec=frontcover)

> In particular, in the case of a mortgage the lender has marketable
> collateral that serves as a **fallback** if the borrower fails to
> repay the loan. [National Academies of Sciences, Engineering and
> Medicine; *Making Medicines Affordable*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Making_Medicines_Affordable/sLlSDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=medication%20no%20fallback&pg=PA79&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: "Fallback" doesn't have the same meaning as default, it has an entirely different meaning and connotation.

Comment: @Tanvir Medicine (for one example) doesn't have defaults like a setting or value in an appliance or system. If you don't have your broken leg treated, it doesn't get a "default" treatment. There can be standard-of-care, traditional, innovative, usual, old-fashion, experimental, folk, and other treatments, but none are "default" in the meaning you allude to.

Comment: "Standard" is good but I prefer "Go-To" as suggested here by @Edwin. Because if I say "Standard", there is a connotation/implication that an authority standardizes something, which may not be the case